# for loop does not work when using crontab in Apple M1

Tags: cron, apple-m1

Just a simple shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/zsh

for file in ~/Desktop/*
do
    echo ${file}
done
```

When it runs in terminal, the output is like:

```
$ ./test
/Users/onns/Desktop/Screen Shot 2021-04-25 at 19.48.46.png
/Users/onns/Desktop/Screen Shot 2021-04-25 at 19.52.42.png
/Users/onns/Desktop/Screen Shot 2021-04-25 at 19.53.38.png
/Users/onns/Desktop/Screen Shot 2021-04-25 at 19.54.03.png
```

Everything is ok, but when I test it via crontab, the output is:

```
/Users/onns/Desktop/test:3: no matches found: /Users/onns/Desktop/*
```

`*` does not expand when using `crontab`, does anyone know why?

the `cron` task is:

```
* * * * * /bin/zsh /Users/onns/Desktop/test >>/Users/onns/Desktop/out.log 2>>/Users/onns/Desktop/err.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix it. You need to grant `cron` **Full Disk Access**, not `crontab`, not `crontab`!

[image: Prvacy]